# $A$ and $B$ disjoint compact subspaces of a Hausdorff $X$. Show there exists disjoints open sets $U,V$ containing $A$ and $B$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I've found the proof for this [here](http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-26-compact-spaces/problem-5-solution/) and I understood completely that it takes a finite amount of open sets $U_\alpha$ from $A$ and, to the correspondents $V_\alpha$ from $B$. The way the open cover was constructed, I know that it'll cover $A$, but there's nothing saying that it'll cover $B$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set which is said to cover $B$ is the *intersection* of the finitely many $V_{\alpha}$ which "go with" the sets $U_{\alpha}$ covering $A.$ It's OK to form a finite intersection of open sets and get an open set. Each individual $V_{\alpha}$ does not meet $A,$ and contains $B,$ so their intersection has the same properties. A picture may help here.

*One detail:* Each of the (finitely many) open sets $U_\alpha$ contains the compact set $A$ and is disjoint from the corresponding open set $V_\alpha$ which contains $B.$ So the union of the $U_\alpha$ is an open set containing $A$ which is disjoint from the (open) intersection of the $B_\alpha$ which covers set $B.$ So what the construction gives is in fact two disjoint open sets, one containing $A$ and the other containing $B,$ in a kind of "generalized" separation situation. [Previously I had only said the pen set covering $B$ was disjoint from $A,$ however one wants it to be disjoint from the open set constructed to contain $A.$]